# How do you infer the integer type from a modulus operation in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Contrived example of code:

```
const someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const remainder = someArray.length % 3;
const someObject = {
  'key0': 'value0',
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
};

const value = someObject[`key${remainder}`]; // TypeScript complains with:
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`key${number}`'
// can't be used to index type '{ key0: string; key1: string; key2: string' }'.
// ts(7053)
```

My understanding is that because JavaScript only has numbers as a concept, TypeScript is doing the safe thing of assuming that the length of the array could be a non-integer number. How can you inform TypeScript that the values being used to calculate `remainder` are integers and thus the result is constrained to 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: The compiler does not understand that arbitrary arrays have integral lengths, and it also doesn't understand that the modulo operation produces outputs in a certain numeric range.  These are all just `number` to the compiler.  How often are you going to be doing this "array length modulo n" operation? If it's only a few times then you might as well just assert `(someArray.length % 3) as 0 | 1 | 2`.  If it's very common then you can write a `arrayLengthMod` function with a strongly typed output.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/m35dEw) for examples.

Comment: Does the above comment meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `someArray.length % 3` to `0 | 1 | 2` so TS would know the range of numbers ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmBBATmghgTxgXhgG0ByTYgGhmICMKrg7iATRpYgXQG4BYAKFEiw0SBJgCWYJkjT44iVBhwA6ADZIwAcygALGAFIYAZhiYIMAAwwAPjACM1mACYe-cNDnIA8tQBWSYLAEAN58MFQA1kjY5sQAXFQAbpgqAK5IMeShEVG2cYnJabmZvGHEkdiOecRJqUiVxQC%20LnwC7jVpsvBevv5QhAAG5QAkQcKiElJoDf1cQA)):

```
const someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const remainder = someArray.length % 3 as 0 | 1 | 2;
const someObject = {
  'key0': 'value0',
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
};

const value = someObject[`key${remainder}`];
```

Another option is to cast `key${remainder}` explicitly as a key of `someObject` ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmBBATmghgTxgXhgG0ByTYgGhmICMKrg7iATRpYgXQG4BYAKFEiw0SBJgCWYJkjT44iVBhwA6ADZIwAcygALGAFIYAZh79w0OcgDy1AFZJgsAgG8%20MKgGsk2AAzEAXFQAbpgqAK5IvuSuHl4AjP5BIeHxUbxuxJ7YAEwJxMFhSDmpAL4mfALm%20eGy8Fa29lCEAAaZACROwqISUmjFTTCYEDCZIABmMFDYAA5IYxZI1nYOXEA)):

```
const someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const remainder = someArray.length % 3;
const someObject = {
  'key0': 'value0',
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
};

const value = someObject[`key${remainder}` as keyof typeof someObject];
```